# current_page? method with different controllers and actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using the `current_page?` method to append 'active' to the li tags that surround my navigation links. `current_page?` will also allow me to handle active links in the sub menus. The sidebar has links that go to different controllers and actions throughout the app. However clicking the last link in the sidebar (link_to edit_lender_registration_path) I receive the following error:

> No route matches {:action=>"dashboard",
>   :controller=>"lenders/lender_account"}

I'm not sure where it is getting `:controller=>"lenders/lender_account"` from. I haven't specified that controller in any of the if statements.

My _sidebar.html.erb :

```
<!-- Begin Sidebar Menu -->
<div class="col-md-3" id="small">
  <ul class="list-group sidebar-nav-v1" id="sidebar-nav">
    <% if current_page?(controller: 'lender_account', action: 'dashboard') %>
      <li class="list-group-item active">
    <% else %>
      <li class="list-group-item">
    <% end %>
        <%= link_to root_path do %>
          <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> My Account
        <% end %>
      </li>
    <% if current_page?(controller: 'lender_account', action: 'pending_loans') %>
      <li class="list-group-item active">
    <% else %>
      <li class="list-group-item">
    <% end %>
        <%= link_to pending_loans_path do %>
          <i class="fa fa-refresh"></i> Pending Loans
        <% end %>
      </li>
    <% if current_page?(controller: 'lender_account', action: 'portfolio') %>
      <li class="list-group-item active">
    <% else %>
      <li class="list-group-item">
    <% end %>
        <%= link_to portfolio_path do %>
          <i class="fa fa-folder"></i> Loan Portfolio
        <% end %>
      </li>
    <% if current_page?(controller: 'lender_account', action: 'loan_payments') %>
      <li class="list-group-item active">
    <% else %>
      <li class="list-group-item">
    <% end %>
        <%= link_to loan_payments_path do %>
          <i class="fa fa-money"></i> Loan Payments
        <% end %>
      </li>

      <!-- Sub menu -->
      <li class="list-group-item list-toggle">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#sidebar-nav" href="#collapse-transactions"><i class="fa fa-exchange"></i> Transactions</a>
        <ul id="collapse-transactions" class="collapse">
          <li><%= link_to "Overview", overview_lender_transaction_path(current_user) %></li>
          <li><%= link_to "Deposits", deposits_lender_transaction_path(current_user) %></li>
          <li><%= link_to "Withdrawals", withdrawals_lender_transaction_path(current_user) %></li>
          <li><%= link_to "Loan Transactions", loan_transactions_lender_transaction_path(current_user) %></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <!-- End Sub menu -->
    <% if current_page?(controller: 'lenders/registrations', action: 'edit') %>
      <li class="list-group-item active">
    <% else %>
      <li class="list-group-item">
    <% end %>
        <%= link_to edit_lender_registration_path do %>
          <i class="fa fa-user"></i> Account Settings
        <% end %>
      </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<!-- End Sidebar Menu -->
```

The applicable routes :

```
  devise_for :users, skip: :registrations do get '/users/sign_out' => 'devise/sessions#destroy' end
  devise_for :lenders, skip: :sessions, :controllers => {:registrations => "lenders/registrations"}
  devise_for :businesses, skip: :sessions, :controllers => {:registrations => "businesses/registrations"}

    resources :businesses, :only => [] do
        resource :supp_form
        resource :loan_application
    end 

    resources :lenders, :only => [] do
        resource :loan_part
        resource :transaction do
            get :overview, :on => :collection
            get :deposits, :on => :collection
            get :withdrawals, :on => :collection
            get :loan_transactions, :on => :collection
        end 
    end

    # Lender Routes
    get 'portfolio', to: 'lender_account#portfolio'
    get 'balances', to: 'lender_account#balances'
    get 'pending_loans', to: 'lender_account#pending_loans'
    get 'loan_payments', to: 'lender_account#loan_payments'
    match '/accounts/:id', to: 'lender_account#dashboard', :as => 'account', via: [:get]
```

Comment: Post the contents of your "routes.rb" file please.

Comment: @Touch Thank you for the reminder..I forgot they were applicable here.